# PC doesn't power up anymore

Tags: power

I will tell you the story behind the problem.

The OS needed to be re installed.  It has 2 HDDs so I had to un-plug one to see which is which, to save as much data as possible. After unplugging the first one, it booted with the installation CD.

It wasn't the HDD I was looking for so I turned it off and unplugged the other one. After unplugging and turning on, right after booting test, the HDD was turned off and the only thing that was working was the CPU fan.  I turned it off the switch on the  power supply, holding the power button didn't do it.

Now it doesn't turn on anymore. I tried with another test power supply but the result was the same, it won't turn on. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

The odds are high you knocked a wire loose somewhere.  Check everything, if you don't find anything unplug the power wires and plug them back in.  (A plug can *LOOK* seated and yet not be.)  Do the same with the wires from the case to the motherboard.

Comment: I tried this. Changed the power supply with another one, unplugged the power up button's wire and plugged a jumper instead with no success after turning the power supply on. Isn't it supposed to turn on?